# Why don't pyroxenites and peridotites appear in Streckeisen's QAPF diagram?

Tags: rocks, petrology, igneous

Wikipedia says for [QAPF diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAPF_diagram):

> "A QAPF diagram is a double ternary diagram which is used to classify
>   igneous rocks based on mineralogic composition."

Why don't pyroxenites and peridotites appear on this diagram?

Aren't they igneous rocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why don't pyroxenites and peridotites appear on this diagram?

Because they do not have any quartz, feldspars, or felspathoids.

The same Wikipedia page also says this:

> QAPF diagrams are also not used if mafic minerals make up more than 90% of the rock composition (for example: peridotites and pyroxenites).

Instead, we use a different diagram, that has olivine, orthopyroxene, and clinopyroxene at the vertices. [Like this one right here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Peridotite_Olivine-Orthopyroxene-Clinopyroxene_-_Common_Peridotites_highlighted.png).

> Aren't they igneous rocks?

Not necessarily, actually. But that's a completely different question.

Comment: I guess some peridotites and pyroxenites reach metamorphism and so they are not igneous.